# In a file with two word lines, grep only those lines which have both words from a whitelist

Tags: awk, grep, whitelist

I have a file1:

```
green
yellow
apple
mango
```

and a file2:

```
red apple
blue banana
yellow mango
purple cabbage
```

I need to find elements from file2 where both words belong to the list in file1. So it should show:

> yellow mango

I tried:

```
awk < file2 '{if [grep -q $1 file1] && [grep -q $2 file1]; then print $0; fi}'
```

I am getting syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}($1 in a)&&($2 in a)' file1 file2 
yellow mango
```

**Explanation:**

`NR` is a special `awk` variable the tracks the current line in the input and `FNR` tracks the current line in each individual file so the condition `NR==FNR` is only true when we are in the first file. `a` is a associative array where the keys are each unique line in the first file. `$0` is the value of the current line in `awk`. The `next` statement jumps to the next line in file to the next part of skip is not executed. The final part is straight forward if the first field `$1` is in the array `a` and the second field then print the current line. The default block in `awk` is `{print $0}` so this is implicit.

Comment: thanks. it works great...would be very helpful if you could break it down and explain how this works.

Comment: @user2312196 added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with bash, sed and grep:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' file1) file2  | grep -f <(sed 's/$/$/' file1)
```

this is a bit obscure, so I will break it down:

`grep -f <file>` reads a sequence of patterns from a file and will match on any of them.

`<(...)` is `bash` [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) and will execute a shell command and create a pseudo-file with the output that can be used in place of a filename.

`sed 's/^/^/' file1` inserts a `^` character at the start of each line in file1, turning the lines into patterns that will match the first word of file2.

`sed 's/$/$/' file1` inserts a `$` character at the end, so the patterns will match the second word.

**Edit**:
Use:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/;s/$/\b/' file1) file2  | grep -f <(sed 's/$/$/;s/^/\b/' file1)
```

to get round the issue that Jonathan pointed out in his comment.

Comment: Being horribly picky, if a line in the second file was 'greengage earthapple', your command would pick it up because the it matches 'green' at the start of the line and 'apple' at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hackish approach and probably frowned upon by many of the grep/sed implementors. In addition it is probably terminal dependent. You have been warned.

GNU grep, when in color mode, highlights pieces of the input that were matched by one of the patterns, this could in theory, be used as a test for a full match. Here, this even works in practice, that is, with some help from GNU sed:

```
grep --color=always -f file1 file2 | sed -n '/^\x1b.*\x1b\[K *\x1b.*\x1b\[K$/ { s/\x1b\[K//g; s/\x1b[^m]*m//gp }'
```

Output:

```
yellow mango
```

Note that the sed pattern assumes space separated columns in `file2`.